# Solve $\frac{dy}{dx}+7\frac{y}{x} = \frac{1}{x^2} , y(1)=2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried to solve it, but I get an answer with absolute values when I find the integration factor. The solution manual says that the answer is $y=\frac{\left(\frac{x^6}{6}+\frac{11}{6}\right)}{x^7}. $ I checked it out on this page [Ordinary Differential Equation Calculator](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/ordinary-differential-equation-calculator/y'%2B%5Cfrac%7B7%7D%7Bx%7D%5Ccdot%20y%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%7D%20%2Cy%5Cleft(1%5Cright)%3D2/?origin=button)

but they don't use that $\int \frac{1}{x}dx=\ln|x|.$ They just say that $\int\frac{1}{x}dx=\ln(x)$...is it correct to do that? Can I just ignore the absolute value?

Comment: set $y=xu$ then is $$y'=u'x+u$$

Comment: But when I find the integrating factor, do I not need to take the absolute value into consideration?

Answer (score 0):

This equation has a singularity at $x = 0$. Since the initial value is given at $x_0 = 1$, the solution is only defined in the domain $x \in (0,\infty)$, and we assume $x > 0$. If there were no initial value and we were asked to find the general solution, then we have to take the absolute value into consideration.

Another explanation is that the solution has the same form whether $x>0$ or $x<0$. If we take the integral as $\int\frac{1}{x} = \ln|x|$, the resulting integration factor would be $\mu(x)=|x|^7$. If $x < 0$, this is $-x^7$. When we multiply this to both sides of the equation, the negative sign cancels. Thus the sign of $x$ has no bearing on the general form of the solution. This is the same reason why we ignore the constant of integration and do not take $\int \frac{1}{x} = \ln|x| + C$.

Answer (score -1):

multiplying by $x^7,$ we have  $$x^7 y' + 7x^6 \, y = \left(x^7 \, y\right ) ' = x^5 \tag 1$$

integrating $(1)$ from $1$ to $x,$ we get $$x^7y - 2= \frac16\left(x^6 - 1\right) $$ you can simplify this to get $y$ in terms of $x.$

Comment: Their question was more about the integral of $\frac1x$ than the differential equation itself. -1